# Golang struct assignability and type identity

Tags: go, struct, types

I have the following 2 structs:

```golang
    func main() {
        type A struct {
            v int
        }
        type B struct {
            v int
        }
        var b B = A{}
    }
```

The assignment `var b B = A{}` fails with an error message:

> Cannot use 'A{}' (type A) as the type B

But in the [golang spec:Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) it says:

> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags. Non-exported field names from different packages are always different.

so, I expect types `A` and `B` to be identical. And in the [spec:Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) it says:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.

given all that information, I tend to think that the assignment should be succeeded since the type of `A{}` is identical to `B`, but apparently I'm missing something.

So, what am I missing here to understand the root cause of the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the definition you pointed to starts with:

```
A defined type is always different from any other type.
```

`A` and `B` are defined types, they have different names, so they are different. The type `struct { v int }` is identical to any type `struct {v int}`, but in this case, these are not defined types. For instance, you can declare:

```
func f(x struct {v int})
```

Then you can call:

```
f(struct {v int}{v:1})
```

The two structs are equal.

You can still assign `A` and `B` using:

```
var b B = B(A{})
```

This works because the underlying types of `A` and `B` are structurally identical.

Answer (score 3):

So given types `A` and `B` *defined* as:

```
    type A struct {
        v int
    }

    type B struct {
        v int
    }
```

**Are the types identical?**

No. From [Type Definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions):

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type

**What are A and B underlying types?**

Both are `struct { v int }`. From

> If `T` is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, **or a type literal**, the corresponding underlying type is T itself.

So given that a type declaration is in the form `TypeSpec = AliasDecl | TypeDef .` and `TypeDef = identifier Type .` you can pattern-match your types and see that both `A` and `B` conform to the type definition where:

- `A` and `B` are the *identifiers* and
- `struct { v int }` is their underlying struct *type literal*.

**How does assignment work?**

From [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) you can see that no condition applies:

- *x's type is identical to T.* — `A` and `B` are not identical because both are different defined types
- *x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.* — both are defined types

So a variable of type `A` is not assignable to a variable of type `B` and vice-versa. Non-assignability also means that you can't pass a variable of type `A` to a function parameter of type `B`, [because](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls):

> arguments must be single-valued expressions assignable to the parameter types of `F`

The example in Burak's answer with `func foo(x struct{ v int })` compiles because `foo`'s param type is a struct literal, not a defined type, and falls under the conditions for assignability.

**How does conversion work?**

You can convert from `A` to `B` because, from [Conversion`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> - [...]
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T have *identical underlying types*.

And we proved above that both structs do indeed have identical underlying types. Therefore this compiles:

`var a A = A(B{})`

---

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UyEYrbUufA5